# Php get string from <tag></tag> and add htmlentities to string

Tags: php, html-entities

I have a string from database who contains multiple `<code></code>` html tags.
I was wondering, how can i show it in web page like in here. Visitor can see the text and the code snippets. for the `<code></code>` tags have a class with programming language. Like: `This is some description text and code example <code class="language-php"><?php echo "Hello world!!"; ?> </code> more description <code class="language-css">body{bacground-color:red;}</code> and more text`

Comment: what have you tried so far? i don't see any code

Comment: I don't know how even start

Comment: you have a class values , use them like  `.language-php {/*css here*/}`

Comment: Are you looking for [`pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)? I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: I have a string ho contains `<code></code>` and between tags ar some code snippets. I wan't add to the code snippets php htmlentities() funtion

Comment: You should use the `htmlentities()` function (I would just use `htmlspecialchars()` though) on the whole string. When you only escape what is in `<code>` people can still do XSS outside of it. When you've done that you can just use CSS to style everything. `<code>` shouldn't mean anything to PHP, it should only mean something to your CSS and possibly your JavaScript.

Comment: This text `This is some description text and code example <code class="language-php"><?php echo "Hello world!!"; ?> </code> more description <code class="language-css">body{bacground-color:red;}</code> and more text` is coming all from database, if i do htmlentities() or htmlspecialchars() `<code class="language-php"></code>` is displayed on screen and do no styling...

Comment: how it works here with these `` ??

Answer (score 0):

There are some **js library** can do this **like** :

- [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)
- [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/)

**And** if you don't need library check Out this **simple demo**

```css
pre {
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #BCBEC0;
    background: #F1F3F5;
    font:12px Monaco,Consolas,"Andale  Mono","DejaVu Sans Mono",monospace
}

code {
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid #BCBEC0;
    padding: 2px;
    font:12px Monaco,Consolas,"Andale  Mono","DejaVu Sans Mono",monospace
}

pre code {
    border-radius: 0px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px; 
    border: 0px;
    padding: 2px;
    font:12px Monaco,Consolas,"Andale  Mono","DejaVu Sans Mono",monospace
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
</code>
</pre>

This is <code>inline</code> code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, text from textarea saving with htmlentities(); Text is something like this:
`Button: <pre><code class="language-html"><button>Test</button></code></pre>`
To show it to page from database i use html_entity_decode(); It's works fine with php, css, javascript code blocks, but no for html...